# Why are my labels being displayed at the same time in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is an example code of my problem:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def large_list():
    my_list = [i for i in range(100000000)]


def make_large_list():
    my_label = Label(root, text='0% completed')
    my_label.pack()

    large_list()

    my_label2 = Label(root, text='Completed')
    my_label2.pack()


my_button = Button(text='Do something', command=make_large_list)
my_button.pack()

mainloop()
```

The `large_list()` function takes about 10 seconds to complete.

When `my_button` is clicked, after waiting for 10 seconds, it displays `my_label` and `my_label2` on the screen at the same time, which is not what I expected. I wanted to immediately display `my_label` on the screen since it was just packing a simple text label, and then, after waiting for those 10 seconds, display `my_label2` on the screen since it has to go through the `large_list` function.

to make it easier to undestand, I want something like this:
[image]

What I get instead is this:
[image]

I tried doing the same thing without tkinter and just priting the text labels in the following code:

```
def large_list():
    my_list = [i for i in range(100000000)]


def make_large_list():
    print('0% completed')

    large_list()

    print('Completed')


my_input = input('Wanna do something? yes/no\n')

if my_input == 'yes':
    make_large_list()
```

and surprisingly for me, it works exactly like I wanted. After I input `'yes'`, it prints `'0% completed'` inmediatly, and after waiting 10 seconds, it prints `'Completed'`, so how can I get the same thing to work in tkinter?

Comment: tkinter is single threaded. While your list comprehension is running there's no way for tkinter to draw the window.

Comment: I recommend that you check generators in python (https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/), if you need that the button remains unresponsive for 10 seconds, you might want to use the (from time import sleep) sleep("time you want the program to remain unresponsive").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that inside `make_large_list()` none of your actions update the GUI. Its only when that function ends that `tkinter` takes control and processes all the changes.

Note how when you click on the button is stays in the down state and never animates back to the up state.

However, you can force `tkinter` to do an update inbetween like this:

```py
def make_large_list():
    my_label = Label(root, text='0% completed')
    my_label.pack()
    root.update()

    large_list()

    my_label2 = Label(root, text='Completed')
    my_label2.pack()
```